# Column of Map type in springBoot table

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Table in spring boot in which one column i want to be of Map type. Below is the model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "media")
public class Media {

@NotBlank
private String url;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Long id;

    @ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="metaData",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="media_id"))
Map<String, Object> metaData= new HashMap<>();

}
```

I m getting error for metaData type. The error is "collection element mapping has wrong number of column metaData.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define how the mapping table should be.

```java
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="media_meta_data",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="media_id"))
@MapKeyColumn(name="meta_key")
@Column(name="meta_value")
Map<String, Object> metaData= new HashMap<>();
```

`MapKeyColumn` annotation defines a column in `media_meta_data` corresponding to keys of the map.

`Column` annotation defines a column in `media_meta_data` corresponding to values of the map.

And there is another key for relating to `Media` model in the joining table named `media_id` that you define in `CollectionTable` annotation.

Comment: @Aashish Please double check you use the same code in the answer. Maybe the error is another thing now